# Algorithm to find a square shape in an image?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have an image with, say, a circle and a square. Is there a way to find the square given the matrix of the image? (there is only one square, and time is not really an issue).
Thanks.

Comment: Is it a perfect square, or "square-like"?

Comment: Rectangle, to be precise. But it's quite a vanilla. Suppose it's been drawn with MS Paint "square" tool, and then saved as gif.

Comment: Is the square aligned to the axes or is it rotated?

Comment: Is there a known background color?

Comment: @thejh: white or transparent. the lines of the shapes are always black.

Comment: so it isn't solid, just a border line? and the inside is also white/transparent?

Comment: just a border line, and yes, besides a few pixels here and there, the inside of the box is the same color as the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's divide all points into "lit" and "dark".

Look for points which are lit, and the points above and below are also lit. Those are likely to be a part of an edge.

Similarly: if a point (x,y) is lit and points (x+1,y), (x+2,y) are also lit, but (x-1,y) and (y-1,y) are dark, and analogously in the Y-direction, then you've most likely found an upper-left corner. And so on. In this way you can find the corners and then find the square from them - seems to be a simple approach.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
for (x,y of every black pixel) {
 #those methods should return true if the lines length is more than one pixel
 if (hasLineToRight(x,y)&&hasLineToBottom(x,y)) {
  otherx=highestXOfLineToRight();
  othery=highestYOfLineToBottom();
  if (isLine(x,y,x,othery)&&isLine(x,y,otherx,y)) {
   addBoxToList(x,y,otherx,othery);
  }
 }
}
```

[image: box image]

You propably want to use the box with the highest width and height values.

Answer (score 0):

If the square in the image is perfect, check that there is a border in the expected position.   The pseudocode in thejh's answer should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, Gintautas. Sorry to ask you this, but could you be a little more formal? Some math, or pseudo-code maybe? I'm having trouble parsing the sentence. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, my first sentence was broken, sorry. Fixing.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you were looking for a filled  rectangle rather than just the countour, as provided by Paint's "Rectangle" tool. In this case the solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What about [flood filling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) starting at random points until you found your rectangle ?